# Unable to retrieve some property values of the saved objects in Realm Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, realm

I'm new to Realm and Xamarin.iOS and I'm a bit confused as to why my saved objects are not persisted after retrieving it once in Realm. Below is the main object which I am using to save the inputs by the user.

```
public class UserSelections : RealmObject
{
  public UserSelections() {}

  [PrimaryKey]
  public string FormId { get; private set; }
  public bool IsEntry { get; set; }
  public Class1 ClassNo1 { get; set; }
  public Class2 ClassNo1 { get; set; }
  public string Site { get; set; }
  public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `Class1` and `Class2` also inherits `RealmObject`.

Here's the scenario that hits the issue:

1. Initialize the `UserSelections` object for the first time after the user answers the first series of questions and save them in the realm.

   ```
   realm.Write(() => 
   {
      var newData = new NewData(); // Inherits the RealmObject
      realm.Add(newData);
      var userSelections = new UserSelections
      {
        FormId = "123TEST",
        IsEntry = true,
        ClassNo1 = userEntryClass1,
        ClassNo2 = userEntryClass2,
        Site = "Some site",
        State = "Some state here"
      };

      realm.Add(userSelections);
   }
   ```
2. On syncing the data, retrieve the data that is stored and set it in the class to be sent to the API. That `UserData` class does not inherit the `RealmObject`

   ```
   var completedForms = realm.All<UserSelections>().Where(frm => frm.Completed).ToList();
   var dataToAPI = new List<UserData>();
   foreach(var form in completedForms) 
   {
       UserData data = new UserData
       {
          FormId = form.FormId,
          IsEntry = form.IsEntry,
          IntegerProperty1 = form.ClassNo1.Id, 
          IntegerProperty2 = form.ClassNo2.Id, 
          Site = form.Site,
          State = form.State
       }
       dataToAPI.Add(data);
   }
   ```
3. Send the data to the API. In here replicate the failure sending by throwing an exception
4. Repeat step 2 by retrieving the object again. However, `form.ClassNo1` and `form.ClassNo2` are null objects already.

I'm not really sure why it doesn't persist when it should have retrieved it again. I already updated the Realms package to the latest version but it still doesn't retrieve again the saved data. Do I need to re-save it again in order for it to persist?

Comment: You should not need to persist things again. It's not obvious to me what the problem is but if you can isolate the issue in a standalone app that reproduces it, please file a ticket at https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues.

Comment: I may be mis-reading the code, but it looks like there are a number of issues in the code and some of it is not clear as to it's purpose. For example; `UserSelections` has a property `FormId` but when it's read like this `form.FormID,` - `Id` vs `ID`. Also `Where(frm =>` - the query could return multiple results `var form =` so attempting to read a single object won't work like that. This `realm.Add(newData);` is an empty object so.. ? Also, we don't see where ClassNo1 is added to perhaps the issue? see [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Corrected some changes here.  The data passed to `ClassNo1` is an object passed from outside of the function. And this also inherits `RealmObject`.

Comment: Hi @NikolaIrinchev , the issue is metioned in step 4 wherein it doesn't seem to persist whenever I try to retrieve the data the second time based of the same ID.

Comment: The issue still isn't clear and I think some troubleshooting would help. First, can you verify that the object(s) are actually written and exist in Realm. Then what does this `var completedForms` contain after that line completes? Then from `var dataToAPI = new List<UserData>();` down, can you step through that code   line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? Then report back your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the issue was to (1) upgrade the Realms to the latest version, and (2) to inherit the `EmbeddedObject` class to the classes which I am working on.

Thanks so much for the help!